# Proving the existence of a unique set constructed from two given sets

Tags: set-theory

Let $M$ and $N$ be sets. Show that there exists a unique set $Q$ such that $x \in Q$ if and only if either $x \in M $ and $ x \notin N $ or $ x \in N $ and $ x \notin M $.

Here is my attempt. First, we will prove the existence of $Q$. Here we will use [axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification)

$$\forall w\,\forall A\, \exists B\,\forall x \big(x \in B \Leftrightarrow [x \in A \wedge \varphi(x, w)] \big) $$

Now, if we let $A = M$ and $w = N$ and $\varphi(x, w) = x \notin w = x \notin N$ then we get the following using universal instantiation

$$ \exists B\,\forall x \big(x \in B \Leftrightarrow [x \in M \wedge x \notin N] \big) $$

Now, if we let $P_1 = B$, then using existential instantiation, we get a set $P_1$ such that

$$\forall x \big(x \in P_1 \Leftrightarrow [x \in M \wedge x \notin N] \big) \cdots\cdots (1)$$

In a similar way, if we let $A = N$ and $w = M$ and $\varphi(x, w) = x \notin w = x \notin M$ then we get a set $P_2$ such that

$$\forall x \big(x \in P_2 \Leftrightarrow [x \in N \wedge x \notin M] \big) \cdots\cdots (2)$$

Now, that we have $P_1$ and $P_2$, we can use [axiom of pairing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_pairing)

$$\forall A\, \forall B \, \exists C\,\forall D\, [ D \in C \Longleftrightarrow (D = A \vee D = B)] $$

Letting, $A = P_1$ and $B = P_2$ and then using universal instantiation, we get

$$ \exists C\,\forall D\, [ D \in C \Longleftrightarrow (D = P_1 \vee D = P_2)]  $$

and further using existential instantiation, we get a set $C$ such that

$$ \forall D\, [ D \in C \Longleftrightarrow (D = P_1 \vee D = P_2)]  $$

By caling $C = P_3$, we have the a set $P_3$ such that

$$ \forall D\, [ D \in P_3 \Longleftrightarrow (D = P_1 \vee D = P_2)]\cdots\cdots (3)  $$

Now, we will prove that $P_3$ is same set as $\{P_1, P_2 \}$. Let $x \in P_3$ be some arbitrary element. Then using eq (3), we conclude that $x = P_1 \vee x = P_2$. In either case, $x \in \{P_1, P_2 \} $. In other direction, if $x \in \{P_1, P_2 \} $, then $x = P_1 \vee x = P_2$. So, using equation (3) again, we can see that $x \in P_3$. So, invoking [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality), we can see that $P_3 = \{P_1, P_2 \} $. So, finally, we will use [axiom of union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union)

$$\forall A\, \exists B\, \forall c\, (c \in B \Longleftrightarrow \exists D(c \in D \wedge D \in A)) $$

If we let $A = P_3$, then using universal instantiation, we get

$$ \exists B\, \forall c\, (c \in B \Longleftrightarrow \exists D(c \in D \wedge D \in P_3)) $$

Lets call $B = P_4$. So, using existential instantiation, we get a set $P_4$ such that

$$ \forall c\, (c \in P_4 \Longleftrightarrow \exists D(c \in D \wedge D \in P_3))\cdots\cdots(4) $$

Now, we will prove that $P_4 = P_1 \cup P_2$. Let $x \in P_4$ be some arbitrary element in $P_4$. Then using equation (4), we get that

$$ \exists D(x \in D \wedge D \in P_3) $$

By calling $D = Q$ and using existential instantiation, we get a  $Q$ such that $x \in Q$ and $Q \in P_3$. This means that $Q \in \{P_1, P_2 \} $. So, either $Q = P_1$ or $Q = P_2$. Which means that $x \in P_1 \vee x \in P_2$. Which shows that $x \in P_1 \cup P_2$. In other direction, if $x \in P_1 \cup P_2$. Here we have two cases. If $x \in P_1$ and since $P_1 \in \{P_1, P_2 \}$, then we have some $y$ such that $x \in y$ and $y \in \{P_1, P_2 \}$. This means that we have $y$ such that $x \in y$ and $y \in P_3$. To put in symbols,

$$ \exists y (x \in y \wedge y \in P_3) $$

Using, equation (4), this means that $x \in P_4$. The second case, where $x \in P_2$ also leads to $x \in P_4$ with similar reasoning. So, in any case, if $x \in P_1 \cup P_2$ then $x \in P_4$. This proves that $P_4 = P_1 \cup P_2$. So, using set builder notation and using equations 1 and 2, we can say that

$$ P_4 = \{ x \,| \,(x \in M \wedge x \notin N) \vee (x \in N \wedge x \notin M) \} $$

So here we have proven the existence of set $Q = P_4$. Next stage is to prove the uniqueness of the set $Q$. So assume that there two distinct sets $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ satisfying equation 4.

$$ \forall c\, (c \in Q_1 \Longleftrightarrow \exists D(c \in D \wedge D \in P_3))\cdots\cdots(5) $$

$$ \forall c\, (c \in Q_2 \Longleftrightarrow \exists D(c \in D \wedge D \in P_3))\cdots\cdots(6) $$

Now , we let some arbitrary $x \in Q_1$. Equation 5 leads us to

$$ \exists D(x \in D \wedge D \in P_3) $$

And using equation 6, we can conclude that $ x \in Q_2$. With similar reasoning, we can go in opposite direction and prove that $x \in Q_2$ leads to $x \in Q_1$. Invoking [axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality) this proves $Q_1 = Q_2$ contradicting initial assumption that $Q_1 \ne Q_2$. So, we must have $Q_1 = Q_2$. This proves the uniqueness part. So, we proved both existence and uniqueness parts here.

I am new to learning set theory and wanted to check my proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the general form of axiom schema of specification, i.e.
$$\forall w_1 \forall w_2\,\forall A\, \exists B\,\forall x \big(x \in B \Leftrightarrow [x \in A \wedge \varphi(x, w_1,w_2)] \big) $$

then you can just chose

$$\varphi(x, w_1,w_2) \equiv (x \in w_1 \wedge \neg(x \in w_2)) \vee (\neg (x \in w_1) \wedge x \in w_2)$$ with $w_1 = M$, $w_2 = N$ and $A = M \cup N$.

Comment: Yes, I could have shortened it that way. Nice. But is my long reasoning ok ?

Comment: If you are using $A = M \cup N$, then you will have to construct this set using axiom of pairing and axiom of union before you use it here. Is that right ?

Comment: Axiom of union yes. I don’t see why pairing axiom should be used here.

Comment: $M \bigcup N$ can be constructed from applying axiom of union to $\{M, N \}$. And to construct $\{M, N \}$ from $M$ and $N$, we will need to use axiom of pairing. Is that correct ?